# Custom 'fontFamily' is not working in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am a fresher for 'Flutter' and I tried to add a new font family from google fonts to my app.
I followed these steps.

1. Download google font (IndieFlower-Regular.ttf)
2. Created a folder 'fonts' in the root directory and copied the .tff
   file.
3. Added it to pubspec.yaml file and get dependencies.
4. Added into .dart file as follows

   style: TextStyle( color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'IndieFlower'), ),
   https://github.com/ChkBuk/FlutterPlayground/tree/master

But when run the application, its font family does not apply. Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: Post your pubspec.yaml and ThemeData() to know exact cause.
Btw Google fonts has it's official plugin which you can easily use: https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Comment: @AmitB10 Thanks. [pub.dev/packages/google_fonts] works for me, the plugin is easier than manually adding.

Comment: the package will handle the fonts, you don't need to download and bundle it in your app, this is a great way to reduce size (if you have multiple google fonts in your app)

Answer (score 3):

as per your yaml file, you are adding font in the root, but it should be coming inside assets section

```
......
fonts:
  - family: IndieFlower
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf
.....
```

in actual, it should be used like below

```
assets
  - fonts:
    - family: IndieFlower
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: you finally helped  me

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error after doing all the necessary things , its the font family , flutter allows only some fonts in app , I don't the main reason , for my app , I needed Bench nine
font family but after doing all the necessary things , it did not work , I search too , but then I found the same reason above I written  , Change font family